# Updating User Role

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have my admin form working and the users are listed on it. However I'm having huge issues when it comes to updating a user. I get the following error trace.

> Couldn't find User with id=User2

Below is my users controller for admin, I'm looking at the update area.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!


  def index
    authorize! :index, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @users = User.all
    @books = Book.where(approved: false)
    @snippets = Snippet.where(approved: false)
  end

  def show
    @snippet = Snippet.where(approved: false)
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @book = Book.where(approved: false)
  end

  def update
    authorize! :update, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @role = Role.find(params[:user][:role_ids]) unless params[:user][:role_ids].nil?
    params[:user] = params[:user].except(:role_ids)
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:role_id])
      @user.update_plan(role) unless role.nil?
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end


  def destroy
    authorize! :destroy, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    unless user == current_user
      user.destroy
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "Can't delete yourself."
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure what I need to do here and what other information you need. I'm still working on this code and this is my play around app, very new still and still learning new things but would really appreciate getting my head around the updating of roles. attr_accessible is all correct with role_id and role_id is in the user tables but I don't think it sending me to the right place with the below:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"GCnVzWUzSAwb9f0oxSYrAW/ZiuoZg4Yh2qULFiNe+Ls=",
 "user"=>{"role_ids"=>"3"},
 "commit"=>"Change Role",
 "id"=>"User2"}
```

I'm so very confused.

_Form using for updating:

```
<div id="role-options-<%= user.id %>" class="modal" style="display: none;">
  <%= simple_form_for user, :url => user_path(user), :html => {:method => :put, :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
    <div class="modal-header">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&#215;</a>
      <h3>Change Role</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <%= f.input :role_ids, :collection => Role.all, :as => :radio_buttons, :label_method => lambda {|t| t.name.titleize}, :label => false, :item_wrapper_class => 'inline', checked: user.role_ids.first %>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <%= f.submit "Change Role", :class => "btn" %>
      <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">Close</a>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  after_create :assign_default_role
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  def assign_default_role
    add_role(:clerk)
  end


  belongs_to :role
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :profile_name, :password, 
  :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :approved, :role_id



    def setup_default_role_for_new_users
    self.roles = [ "default" ]
  end



  validates :first_name, presence: true

  validates :last_name, presence: true

  validates :profile_name, presence: true,
                           uniqueness: true,
                           format: {
                             with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/,
                             message: 'Must be formatted correctly.'
                           }
  has_many :books
  has_many :snippets
  has_many :statuses
  has_many :user_friendships
  has_many :friends, through: :user_friendships,
                     conditions: { user_friendships: { state: 'accepted' } }

  has_many :pending_user_friendships, class_name: 'UserFriendship',
                                      foreign_key: :user_id,
                                      conditions: { state: 'pending' }
  has_many :pending_friends, through: :pending_user_friendships, source: :friend

   def full_name
    name = "#{first_name.capitalize} #{last_name.capitalize}"
  end

  def to_param
    profile_name
  end

  def gravatar_url
    stripped_email = email.strip
    downcased_email = stripped_email.downcase
    hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(downcased_email)

    "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}"
  end
end
```

Console Output:

Am I reading this right, looks like it's changing user_id to 4.

```
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  ←[1m←[36mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "us
ers_roles"."user_id" = 1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))
  ←[1m←[36mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" ←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mRole Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id"
 WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id"
 WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mRole Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles"
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "roles".id FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHE
RE "users_roles"."user_id" = 1←[0m
  Rendered users/_user.html.erb (4.0ms)
  ←[1m←[35mRole Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id"
 WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = 2 LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id"
 WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = 2 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles"
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "roles".id FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHE
RE "users_roles"."user_id" = 2←[0m
  Rendered users/_user.html.erb (4.0ms)
  ←[1m←[35mRole Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id"
 WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = 3 LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id"
 WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = 3 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles"
  ←[1m←[36m (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "roles".id FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHE
RE "users_roles"."user_id" = 3←[0m

      Rendered users/_user.html.erb (4.0ms)
      ←[1m←[35mRole Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id"
     WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = 4 LIMIT 1
      ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id"
     WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = 4 LIMIT 1←[0m
      ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles"
      ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "roles".id FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHE
    RE "users_roles"."user_id" = 4←[0m
      Rendered users/_user.html.erb (5.0ms)
      ←[1m←[35mBook Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."approved" = 'f'
      Rendered books/_book.html.erb (1.0ms)
      ←[1m←[36mSnippet Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "snippets".* FROM "snippets" WHERE "snippets"."approved" = 'f'←[0m
      Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (34.0ms)
      ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHER
    E "users_roles"."user_id" = 1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))
      ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE
     "users_roles"."user_id" = 1 AND (((roles.name = 'editor') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))←[0m
```

Comment: Post your form from where you are updating

Comment: Please show your `User` class.

Comment: Seems you have wrong routes. URL to `edit` must look like `/admin/user/USER_ID`, where `USER_ID` is integer (in common case).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

you should have:

```
@user = User.find_by_profile_name!(params[:id])
```

You have this error because you pass profile_name in params, but you try to search for user by its id.

You should also modify your line

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:role_id])
```

to:

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

Comment: This worked but now it doesn't change the role_id to the relevant new id, ie: 2 to 3 etc

Comment: You are using `if @user.update_attributes(params[:role_id])` but `params[:role_id]` is not defined. At least in the question you show it is `"user"=>{"role_ids"=>"3"}`. So, what you want will look like `@user.update_attribute("role_id", params[:user][:role_ids])`.

Comment: Ok this works and gives me the redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated." but when I check the console, my role_id for the current user is still 2

Comment: @Featalion I've updated this now and it seems to be changing the user_id but I've put the console output up.

Answer (score -1):

In your update action try changing this:

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

to this:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

The clue is in your error:

```
Couldn't find User with id=User2
```

Comment: Sorry that wasn't meant to be there. I was just testing but then looked at roots. This error is happening with that line still.

Comment: @ShaunFrostDukeJackson could you paste `User` class code into your question? Do you have `User#to_param` method reimplemented?

Comment: No I don't and don't quite understand this method?

Comment: 'that wasn't meant to be there' @ShaunFrostDukeJackson have u updated the question.